# AJAX resize div width for logged in users

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have users that post many different posts with set width x. While any user is idling on the page, I want the width to change for any post that its author logs in. I want it to be real time so no refresh is needed. The 10 seconds is just for testing, i will make it 15-20 seconds when it's ready.

I know there is a better way to do this but don't know how to do that, where you check all the user's that are online with ajax then change the width for these users only..

**AJAX CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                          
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === "online") {
                    $('.status #check_<?php echo $user_id; ?>').css({width: '100px'});  
                } else { 
                    $('.status #check_<?php echo $user_id; ?>').css({width: '50px'});
                }
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

**The main page with the posts**

```
//$user_id is retrieved from another while loop of the posts table
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
     echo '<div class="status" id="check_'.$user_id.'">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
   }
```

**user.php**

```
if (logged_in() === true){  
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE status=1 LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
           if ($row['status'] === "1") {   echo "online";   }
        }   
}else {     echo "offline";    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: does the login take place via ajax?

Comment: why this much complex? you normally store the user id/username in a session, and check if the session is non empty then change the width there itself

Comment: because i want it to change without a page refresh

Comment: if the user is not logged in then what this `$userid` will return?

Comment: the user_id of the author of the post so that I can pull out info about the author that wrote that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with AJAX

in **users.php**

```
//just check the session

session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
echo 'online';
}
else
{
echo 'offline';
}
```

---

this is normal way

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
//$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
//get authorid
echo '<style type="text/css">
        .status #check_'.$authorid.' {
          width: '100px'        }
        </style>';
}
else
{
echo '<style type="text/css">
        .status {
          width: '50px'        }
        </style>';
}
```

Comment: yeah i know that will work but if the user logs in while im on the page, I will have to refresh to see the change. My whole problem is getting the change happen without the need to refresh, that's why I am using ajax

Comment: yeah,for that the first part of my answer is enough,it will check whether the session(whether the user is logged in/not). then it will print onilne/offilne based on session value.

Comment: oh I see what you are doing there. I missed the "with AJAX" part at the beginning. So i transferred the user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>"; with url: 'users.php?id='+user_id. Now what do I put in the success: function(data) ?